# Efficient image processing with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image-processing

I'm in process of writing photo editing app and I want to know if there any more efficient way to solve my task.

**Task:** GPU-accelerated 2d image processing of float type images on Android with OpenGL/Vulkan and Metal on iOS.

**Current pipeline** is following: UI made with flutter controls C++ backend via dart:ffi that utilizes Halide lang generators to efficiently offload computation to OpenGL or Metal.

I am worried about complexity. Halide has it's own caveats, dart:ffi it's own and usage of C to glue C++ and Dart too.

**Q:** Is there any way to efficiently compute image pixel values with Flutter? Any SkSL API exposure on the roadmap?

Comment: "efficiently compute image pixel values" Did you get to solve that? Thx

Comment: So do you run your Halide lang code on GPU and embedded it into a Flutter build already? BTW, may be you could point to a good place to start with this approach. dart:ffi part is clear. I'm more interested about how to add Halide code build into your Flutter project. To be honest I don't see too much overhead going from C to C++. So the only overhead is from Dart to C and back, which should be acceptable, I think, taking into account all the gains you get from running your image processing code on GPU

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SDK exposes API from the Skia engine through [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html). One way of accessing these API is via packages like [graphx](https://pub.dev/packages/graphx). Since [early 2020](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Metal-on-iOS-FAQ), Flutter renders with Metal on iOS, and OpenGL on Android by default.